# Inheritance and Prototyping event

Tags: jquery, prototype

after reading this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff852808, I tried to create an object WindowSingle which objects created with new constructor behave as a window - when somebody press "X" button at the right top corner, the window is closed (div's css set to display: none;):

```js
var WindowSingle = function(obj) {
  this.obj = obj;
  this.isHidden = false;
  this.obj.show();
  this.events.click.call(this);
};
WindowSingle.prototype.Close = function() {
  this.isHidden = true;
  this.obj.closest('.window').hide();
};
WindowSingle.prototype.events = {
  'click': function() {
    var self = this;
    var obj = this.obj;
    obj.find('.closeX').on('click', function() {
      self.Close();
    });
  }
};
$(document).ready(function() {
      myWindowSingle = new WindowSingle($("#myWindow"));
    });
```

```css
.window {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
  width: 250px;
}
.closeX {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 230px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="window" id="myWindow">
  <span class="closeX">X</span>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</div>
```

My questions are:

1. How this event can be handled in more elegant way in general or something like:
   `WindowSingle.prototype.events = {
     'click .closeX': function() {` 
   as in meteor
2. Why simple calling of 
   `obj.find('.closeX').on('click',self.Close);`
   (as I write for simple jQuery events) won't work.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your first question is really simple. To loop through all your events that might have a CSS selector, just do something like this:

```
var WindowSingle = function (obj) {

    this.obj = obj;
    this.isHidden = false;
    this.obj.show();
    this.registerEvents();

};

WindowSingle.prototype.registerEvents = function () {

    var self = this;

    Object.keys(self.events).forEach(function (key) {

        var parts = key.split(" ");

        // Handle CSS selector.
        if (parts[1]) {

            self.obj.on(parts[0], parts[1], function () {
                self.Close();
            });

        // Handle no CSS selector.
        } else {

            self.obj.on(parts[0], function () {
                self.Close();
            });

        }

    });

}
```

The `.on('click',self.Close)` question is a little more advanced. An event will be bound to the click event in that situation, the problem is the context of the function (what `this` means). jQuery always sets the context of an event handler to the DOM Element, but in this case you need it to be your `WindowSingle` instance. The two solutions to that are to either bind the context or just create a new function.

```
var self = this;

// Bind the context.
obj.find('.closeX').on('click', self.Close.bind(self));

// Create a new function.
obj.find('.closeX').on('click', function () {
    self.Close();
});
```

I hope that helps.